# Simulating click on a styled component tests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

I have a styled Button:

```
const MyButton = styled.button`...`
```

And I render it with an `onClick` prop:

```
<MyButton onClick={props.onClick}>A Button</MyButton>
```

In my tests files for the button I use Enzyme to test the `onClick` (the styled button is imported as 'button'):

```
let counter = 0;
const component = shallow(
     <Button onClick={() => counter++}>
          A Button
     </Button>
);
component.find(Button).simulate('click');
```

In the console I get: `Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.`

When debugging using `component.debug()` I see the element is `<styled.button>...</styled.button>`
I tried changing my `find()` to receive `styled.button` and even adding a class name which I can see when debugging but nothing seems to get the element.

How can I find the element and simulate events on it?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `component.find(Button)` you're trying to find a button inside a button which is not the case in your example. Just go for:

```
let counter = 0;
const component = shallow(
     <Button onClick={() => counter++}>
          A Button
     </Button>
);
component.simulate('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing MyButton then you should import it, and use it:

```
import MyButton from './some-button';
const component = shallow(<MyButton />);
component.find(MyButton).simulate('click');
```

You are however, using  which you're not importing, or using in the real code?

Comment: Hi, sorry if it wasn't clear, I mention I am importing it. The test file has also some jest-dom test which use the imported Button